# How do I build multi sites in magento using wamp server

Tags: .htaccess, wamp, magento-1.7

I am new to magento, I have worked on VirtueMart for joomla for a year now and I noticed it has no multistore ability until a friend introduced me to magento. I have succesfully installed magento(1.7.0.2) into WAMP 2.2 (PHP v5.3.13) on my Windows7.

I succesfully created root categories just as directed here: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html but in my own case, I am using sub-directories (ie `//domain/magento` as main store and `//domain/magento/crunchies` as store2).

A root category was created at the backend for crunchies. I copied both index.php and htaccess from magento folder (`c:/wamp/www/magento`) to crunchies folder (`c:/wamp/www/magento/crunchise`).on the crunchies' copy of index.php, `$mageFilenam =‘app/Mage.php’;` I change it to `$mageFilename=‘../app/Mage.php’;`
 And saved changes, I also open up the copied htaccess file and added the following to the end of it:

```
SetEnvIf Host.*MainWebsite.*MAGE_RUN_CODE= base";

SetEnvIfHost .*www.crunchies.com.*MAGE_RUN_TYPE="cruncies_code";
```

Where website names created at System>manage store  of backend are: Main Website(for main store) and www.crunchies.com (for store2).

When I point to `domain/magento` on my browser, it shows home page but when I point to `domain/magento/crunchies`, I get `:\"mydirectery"../app/Mage.php was not found.`

Please how do I solve this issue? Is there any other setting I'm missing out in my wamp config?